# помогите убрать все лишние и оставить цифры

Tags: python

```
f = open('dog (1).gpx')
for line in f.readlines():
if 'lat' in line:
    print(line)
```

вывод такой

```
        <trkpt lat="54.87237" lon="83.1026">

        <trkpt lat="54.872375" lon="83.1026">

        <trkpt lat="54.872383" lon="83.1026">
```

Comment: еще раз прочтите вопрос и потом уточните, что конкретно вам надо

Answer (score 0):

можно через регулярку сделать

в данном примере регулярка ищет числа в заданной вами конкретной форме

```
import re

text = '<trkpt lat="54.87237" lon="83.1026">'

res = re.findall(r'<trkpt lat="([0-9.]+)" lon="([0-9.]+)">', text)

values = list(map(float, res[0]))

print(values)
```

для поиска чисел вообще можно и так:

```
import re

text = '<trkpt lat="54.87237" lon="83.1026">'

res = re.findall(r'([0-9.]+)', text)

values = list(map(float, res))

print(values)
```

Comment: спасибо но пака я ждал ответ уже все понял import re
f = open('/home/misan/PycharmProjects/pythonProject3/gpx/собакабег1 (1).gpx')
for line in f.readlines():
    if '<trkpt' in line:
        num = re.findall(r"\d+.\d+", line)
        print(num[0] +" "+ n